# How to determine the mime type of a file being hosted by a remote server?

Tags: macos, http, ubuntu, http-headers, mime-types

I am trying to determine the MIME type that my web host uses when a request is made for a particular file hosted on his server.

Suppose I have a url:

```
https://www.mysitename.com/myfile.myextension
```

And I am trying to determine the MIME type my web host uses for ".myextension" files, how can I do so?

I figure there must be some way I can make an HTTP request for the file, and as a result there would be some headers, one of which should specify the MIME type of the file.

How can I do this? Can I use terminal on OSX or Ubuntu or something ?
I'm looking for commands to execute from the terminal to determine the MIME type according to the remote server of my file.

EDIT: Forgot to mention - the url is HTTPS.
EDIT: I cannot log into the terminal on the remote server - I can only log into my terminal on my local machine.

Comment: There is a command called `mimetype` in ubuntu. you can give it a try `mimetype URL`

Comment: It doesn't return a type for my particular file. It does so for other file types like images / text etc.

Comment: I don't think mimetype returns what the SERVER thinks the mime type should be, it returns what mimetype thinks the type is.... I need to know what the server thinks the mimetype. I do not have the ability to log into the terminal on the remote server. Only on my local machine.

Comment: Just verified - mimetype returns what the local machine thinks the mimetype is, not what the remote server thinks it is.

Comment: I managed to use log into the server and use mimetype. If you post it as your answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called `mimetype` which gives mimetypes information. You can give it a try.